# iOS UITableViewCell overflowing contentView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am adding views to a `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView` and some of it is taller than the cell's height. Currently, it just overflows on top of the cells below it, but ideally I would like it to get cropped, so that whatever does not fit in the cell is simply not displayed. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[cell  clipsToBounds:YES]` to prevent anything overflowing the cell

`[cell.contentView  clipsToBounds:YES]` to prevent anything overflowing the contentView itself

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW60)

> Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is NO.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in System 7.1 and later.  Some code in UITableView is repeatedly setting clipsToBounds=NO.  ie:  You can set it to YES, but it will get changed back sometimes.